# R Shiny - Load parameters and data before calling the app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an app who is structured like this one : I want to load parameters (libraries, functions) and data before calling the app. It doesn't work when I run this app script. So my current solution is to load the lines until `df <- ...` in the console then after run the script.

```
TheFileDirectory <- "/.../"

# Libraries and functions
source(paste0(TheFileDirectory, "LibFun script.R"))

# Data
df <- readRDS(file = paste0(TheFileDirectory, "TheData.rds"))

# Call the app
source(paste0(TheFileDirectory, "server.R"))
source(paste0(TheFileDirectory, "ui.R"))

shinyApp(ui = Interface, server = Serveur)
```

How can I avoid doing this ? I'm sure that there is a clean solution but I didn't find it.

Here is the `LibFun script.R` :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

CountPlotFunction <- function(MyData)

    {
  MyPlot <- ggplot(data = MyData, aes(x = MyData)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count", aes(fill = MyData)) +
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..)) +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  return(MyPlot)
}
```

And here is the data (script to do the `TheData.rds`) :

```
var1 <- c("Russia","Canada","Australia","Australia","Russia","Australia","Canada","Germany","Australia","Canada","Canada")
var2 <- c("UnitedStates","France","SouthAfrica","SouthAfrica","UnitedStates","SouthAfrica","France","Norge","SouthAfrica","France","France")
var3 <- c("Brazil","Colombia","China","China","Brazil","China","Colombia","Belgium","China","Colombia","Colombia")
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

TheData <- saveRDS(df, file = paste0(TheFileDirectory, "TheData.rds"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Section: Packaging modules

You seem to have two files for server and ui. So a file global.R would help, since it will be called before the server and ui.

Comment: Thanks. But it works only when the `global.R` file is on the same directory that the `ui.R` and `server.R` files. A solution to allow the `global.R` file (or equivalent) being in another directory ?

Comment: You could call other packages via source() from global. I think it is often used when writing custom input and output bindings.

Comment: if that is what you were looking for you can accept the answer by clicking the "check" sign,...